# Worksheet change, selection change, before doubleclick stop working

Tags: vba, worksheet, eventtrigger

On my sheet I have Worksheet change, selection change and before doubleclick macros.
They work like a charm but sometimes they stop working. They don't trigger at all, even when I do a thing that must trigger them.

When they stop to trigger :
1. If i write a macro like

```
sub test
msgbox "hello" & application.EnableEvents
end sub
```

and play this macro, it works and show me "hello TRUE".

2. If I add msgbox "hello" at the first line in worksheet change macro, and test it with a thing that must trigger it, nothing happen.
3. If I close the workbook and reopen it, that works again like a charm.

I don't know what can stop these macro. I though that if application.events return "TRUE" then these macros must trigger (and eventually cause errors, but they must trigger).
What could I do to test what stop them sometimes ? What could it be ?

Comment: I would have thought it's your events that have been disabled.  Open the Immediate window and type `Application.EnableEvents=TRUE`.  Also check your code - wherever the code exits make sure it enables the events if you've disabled them elsewhere.

Comment: Also - pretty sure `Application.Events` isn't a valid VBA command.  `Application.EnableEvents` will return the state - enabled or disabled, while `Application.EnableEvents=TRUE/FALSE` will change the state.

Comment: Sorry, I test 1. If i write a macro like "sub test msgbox "hello" & application.EnableEvents end sub" and play this macro, it works and show me "hello TRUE". I just edited my first message

Comment: Could you post the actual code you're using in your events.  The current code you've posted wouldn't change the event state as you're just looking at it.  It would need to be something like:  `Sub Test(): Application.EnableEvents = False: MsgBox "Hello": Application.EnableEvents = True: End Sub`  (note:  `Application.EnableEvents = True`)

Comment: Thank you for your answers but I don't understand. When I tested this (msgbox application.EnableEvents) I just wanted to know what is the state of Application.EnableEvents. If it returns TRUE, then the worksheet_change must work, isn't it ?

Comment: Yes, it does work. But think about where you have it (or don't have it in this case) - if you change the value of a cell in a `Worksheet_Change` event, that will fire a `Worksheet_Change` event and you'll be stuck in a loop.  You need to disable events before doing something that will fire the event.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your worksheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = _
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") + 1
End Sub
```

Now enter the number 1 in cell A1.  This will fire the worksheet change event, which will add 1 to the value in cell A1, which will fire the worksheet change event, which will add 1 to the value in cell A1.....

Now look at this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = _
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") + 1

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Now enter a 1 in cell A1.  Event watching is turned off, 1 is added to the value in cell A1 and because event watching is turned off - nothing else happens except it is turned on again after the event would have fired.

Comment: Yes I have Application.EnableEvents = False and Application.EnableEvents = True in every sub at the beginning and at the end to avoid this infinite loop effect and avoir to trigger another macro I don't want to trigger when a macro is already working.

Comment: I think I just found the bug in my code. I have a "On error goto 0" in my worksheet_change (old code, when I wasn't sure how to handle errors...). I think that an error occured and was not handled properly, with "application.EnableEvents = true" at the end. I hope this is it. I also put "application.EnableEvents = true" in workbook_open and workbook_activate to try to put away the bug I had. Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 0):

I think I just found the bug in my code. I have a "On error goto 0" in my worksheet_change (old code, when I wasn't sure how to handle errors...). I think that an error occured and was not handled properly, with "application.EnableEvents = true" at the end. I hope this is it. I also put "application.EnableEvents = true" in workbook_open and workbook_activate to try to put away the bug I had. Thanks for the tips.